# Проблемы с компонентом jComments для joomla

Tags: joomla, cms

Доброго времени суток!

На странице [http://www.minorka.ru/comments/faqs](URL) перестали публиковаться вопросы.
В чем может быть проблема?

Joomla! 2.5.4
Компонент jComments 2.3.0.

Comment: Еще актуально!
Буду признателен за любые наводки =)

Comment: гадание на кофейной гуще